# PowerBI + Snowflake (AWS privateLink): 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, powerbi-desktop

- PowerBI: Version: 2.86.727.0 64-bit (October 2020)
- ODBC Connector: PowerBI's integrated Snowflake ODBC connector (out of the box one)
- Snowflake: .southeast-2.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com
- Authentication: OAuth2.0 integration with AAD

Error Message while connecting from PowerBI:

```
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4) 
      REST request for URL https://bhp_dev.ap-southeast-2.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=6100abf5-7441-4dc8-8b86-35f44ca0e94c&request_guid=257da304-137e-4e39-95b0-edfff416fb0d&warehouse=COST_MONITOR 
    failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=60 msg='SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK' osCode=9 osMsg='Bad file descriptor'
```

Snowflake setup:

- created a security integration to enable SSO as per the [doco link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-powerbi.html)
- created a network policy to include the PowerBI and PowerQueryEditor network addresses
- assigned the network policy to a user

PowerBI setup:

- nothing special.

The SSO works ok when the Snowflake is not using private links.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Snowflake Power BI SSO feature has the following limitations:

AWS PrivateLink and Azure Private Link are not supported. If it is necessary to use either of these two services to connect to Snowflake, use the on-premises gateway to connect. This pathway will not provide single sign-on.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-powerbi.html#limitations